# WordPress wp_login_form redirecting always to dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, arguments, timber

I am adding a custom login form for WordPress that always redirects to the same page, therefore unlocking content on that page that was locked away for non-logged in users.

The problem is, regardless if whether I set the `wp_login_form` argument for `redirect` or not, the login form redirects to the WordPress Dashboard.  My code is below (I am using Timber, which means my templates are written with Twig):

```
{{fn('wp_login_form', {redirect: 'http://myserver.local:8888/', label_username: 'User/Email'})}}
```

I know that the arguments are passed correctly because I can change the label of the username to whatever I want and it shows up.  What is going wrong here?  I'd like to avoid using any plugins if possible...

Answer (score 0):

Your can try this code

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', function( $url, $query, $user ) {

    if(wp_login_url() != $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]){
        return $url;
    }else{
        return $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }

}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect.  I added it to my functions.php, is that right?